# Is it possible to access the controller variable from layout in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Consider under my `cpp\controllers\` I've 5 files like (`AController.php`, `BController.php` etc..)

Each controller has its own public variable like this..

```
AController.php   --- public $variable='Testing';
BController.php   --- public $variable='Bhuvanesh';
```

From my `app\views\main.php`

If `A` controller is called I need the value `Testing`. If `B` controller is called I need `Bhuvanesh`.

Its possible in yii2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should read [Yii2 Views Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#accessing-data-in-views) :

> within the view you can get the controller object by the expression `$this->context`

So, you should simply use this in your view :

```
$this->context->variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the __construct() magic method? this function gets executed right when the class is used. If you make something like

```
public function __construct(){
    echo $this->var; //echo out whatever you want here.
}
```

That's how i would do it.

Comment: in your controller. @Bhuvanesh

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a getter method with same name?

```
class AController {
     public function getVariable() { return 'A'; }
}

class BController {
     public function getVariable() { return 'B'; }
}

class CController {
     public function getVariable() { return 'C'; }
}
```

Then you can call with

```
$controller->variable
```

Comment: For your answer, I have to add the controller classes in layout. I have 50 services to do.. So I planned to create the 50 controllers.. Then I have to add the 50 classes in my layout.

Comment: You could handle this issue in a BaseController. Create a public function getVariable() in BaseController (of each subcontroller) and based on get_class($this) inside the getVariable() you can return different function response.

Comment: then you can call with $controller->getVariable(); not ->variable if he uses the __construct he gets the echo instantly instead of needing to call it :) __construct is basic OOP so i recommend doing that.